# 2 promotional interviews in the same company, 1 day apart. Can I tentatively accept one and then change my mind?

Tags: interviewing, employment

I am currently employed for large organisation and have been for 8 years. Two management posts have become available working in different areas of the same company.

The interviews usually take place followed by a verbal offer the same day.

The interviews are on separate days. Day 2 is my preferred job. So, what if i get offered a job on day one. Do I accept it and then decline if I get an offer on the other job? Or does that make me look bad?

What if I decline job 1 and dont get offered job 2?

This is so stressful. Any advice would be really appreciated.

Comment: What stops you from saying you have another interview next day and you will wait with giving an answer for that to be clear?

Comment: In what part of the world is this where a management position is provided an offer same day (verbal or otherwise)? `This is so stressful.` This will sound a little insensitive - if this is stressful to you, you may not be a proper fit for management. This is a trivial decision compared to some of the things that will be thrown at you. You may have decisions in your hands that affect other peoples' lives and livelihoods. **That** is stressful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most companies will have a policy that will require that when you accept the offer from one internal position, you have to remove your self from consideration from other positions. So If you accept the first offer, you shouldn't go to the 2nd interview.

They do this so they aren't bidding against each other. I have seen this rule in several companies I have worked for.

So if you get an offer from the first team, you will have to tell the second team that you have an offer from the first team and they will need to decide quickly because you have a deadline.

The big question is what do you tell the first team. I noticed that you said they generally make a verbal offer the same day. A verbal offer is nice, but internal offers still need to be in writing. Transfers can have contingencies: if we win the contract; if the customers approves. There can be terms that need to be specified: start date, pay bump, work location. Until those items are specified in writing and all contingencies removed the offer isn't solid enough to cancel the 2nd interview.

In companies that were larger than a couple of dozen employees, their internal job application system required written offer letters for all transfers. The employee had to sign the offer letter, and upload it back into the system. In my experience it took even the best HR departments a day or two to move from verbal to written offer.